How to resolve these make install errors for Python 3.11.9?
I am trying to configure and "make install" Python 3.11.9. However, it just quite without building a lib folder and bin folder is empty. Done on Ubuntu 22:04 installed with Python 3.10.12. Below are just a few.
Commands sent from debug folder:
../configure --prefix=/usr --with-ensurepip=install --enable-optimizations
make -j$(nproc) DESTDIR=/home/user/project/myapp.AppDir install

Error 1: A sample. There are many and they all appear red in color in PyCharm.
/usr/bin/ld: Python/errors.o: in function `_PyErr_Fetch':
/home/user/project/src/Python-3.11.9/debug/../Python/errors.c:428: undefined reference to `__gcov_indirect_call'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/project/src/Python-3.11.9/debug/../Python/errors.c:428: undefined reference to `__gcov_indirect_call_profiler_v4'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/project/src/Python-3.11.9/debug/../Python/errors.c:428: undefined reference to `__gcov_time_profiler_counter'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/project/src/Python-3.11.9/debug/../Python/errors.c:428: undefined reference to `__gcov_time_profiler_counter'
/usr/bin/ld: Python/errors.o: in function `PyErr_GivenExceptionMatches':
/home/user/project/src/Python-3.11.9/debug/../Python/errors.c:255: undefined reference to `__gcov_indirect_call'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/project/src/Python-3.11.9/debug/../Python/errors.c:255: undefined reference to `__gcov_indirect_call_profiler_v4'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/project/src/Python-3.11.9/debug/../Python/errors.c:255: undefined reference to `__gcov_time_profiler_counter'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/project/src/Python-3.11.9/debug/../Python/errors.c:255: undefined reference to `__gcov_time_profiler_counter'
/usr/bin/ld: Python/errors.o: in function `PyErr_ExceptionMatches':
/home/user/project/src/Python-3.11.9/debug/../Python/errors.c:294: undefined reference to `__gcov_indirect_call'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/project/src/Python-3.11.9/debug/../Python/errors.c:294: undefined reference to `__gcov_indirect_call_profiler_v4'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/project/src/Python-3.11.9/debug/../Python/errors.c:294: undefined reference to `__gcov_time_profiler_counter'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/project/src/Python-3.11.9/debug/../Python/errors.c:294: undefined reference to `__gcov_time_profiler_counter'

Error 2:
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:1203: Programs/_freeze_module] Error 1

Error 3: This was the last message that appeared before termination.
# This is an expensive target to build and it does not have proper
# makefile dependency information.  So, we create a "stamp" file
# to record its completion and avoid re-running it.


Autoconf deliberately causes errors to test which dependency versions you have and how those dependencies behave. It's impossible and not desirable in the first place to make every test in a configure script pass, so picking a random subset of such tests and putting them in a post here isn't useful to anyone.

If you want to install arbitrary versions of Python on an arbitrary distro, I'd suggest using an out-of-band package manager to do that for you. The one I personally use and recommend is Nix (see https://nixos.org), but there are plenty more -- GNU Stow, pkgsrc, etc -- and also Python-specific tools (pyenv)

To provide an illustrative example -- let's say you have a software package that supports five different major platforms (Windows, MacOS, modern Linux-y systems, and some old UNIXes). Its configure script will have tests that are expected to only pass on Windows, tests that are expected to only pass on modern Linux, tests that are only expected to pass on legacy UNIX, etc -- so on any given platform maybe only one of the five libc-specific tests is expected to pass, and the others are intended and desired to fail

@CharlesDuffy Just that it fails at the checking stage. I am able to configure and make install Python 3.10.14  but not Python 3.11.

...that way autoconf, when it writes out a header file, is able to set flags reflecting only the capabilities and usage modes that are actually available for the platform at hand.

Fine, but (for example) the gcc -qversion test will fail just as much on 3.10.14 as it does on 3.11; when you just throw random errors into the question without figuring out which specific error causes the overall configure run to fail, you're not doing anything that helps us focus on the problem.

That's why I (strongly!) recommend using Nix -- when you tell Nix to install Python 3.11, it won't reuse the copy of gcc, TCL, and other dependencies that Ubuntu ships, but instead will install its own completely self-contained dependency chain (if it has to do a local compile at all and can't just download binaries), so something that builds on Nix on one distro will build on any other; it gets us out of the business of needing to run down what's different about your system and identifying and root-causing a particular point of failure.

Anyhow, if you are going to try to fix this on your existing distro without a parallel dependency set, start by looking at the logs printed by configure when you run it -- not config.log, but the content written to stdout/stderr. Only when something in a configure script's output is unexpected, refer to the config.log to find details behind why that specific unexpected thing happened.

I get what you mean. So these errors are typical, can't win them all. For 3.11, the bin folder is empty, and there is no lib folder, How do I find out the source of the issue?

Let's back up: Did the ../configure run actually have an error? (If it generated makefiles, then it didn't have an error, so we can move past it). If it didn't have an error, what logs are generated when you run make?

(really, though, let me double down on my advice: don't build your own packages -- use a tool that does it for you).

A shortcut: https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa (https://askubuntu.com/q/1398568/452474). Python 3.11 is there. Not sure what your environment is, but if nothing is messed up with, it should work OOTB. I built the pc032 versions for various platforms (with native tool versions installed): https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries/tree/master/Python.

@CharlesDuffy. I believe the issues are occurring during the make install process. I have updated my question with these. Are they helpful to you diagnosing the issue?

Yes, that helps a lot. We know it's a link-time error, we know it relates to the gcov code coverage framework. Is there a configure flag to disable gcov support? If so, first make clean, then reconfigure with a command line argument to explicitly disable gcov.

(mind, if you don't know that you started from a completely clean tree, make clean may solve the problem itself -- if, say, there were already some object files left over from a prior build attempt that explicitly had coverage enabled. In a smaller project, certainly not Python, sometimes a sloppy maintainer will even leave object files in the published source tarball by mistake)

@CharlesDuffy I have resolved my issue and posted my answer inside my question as my question was closed by another. If possible, pls help reopen my question so that I can transfer my answer into the Answer section. Thanks.

I'm still not very sure that the answer will be helpful to others -- a workaround is not a root-cause, and without a root-cause we don't know how common the issue is or which subset of people with similar symptoms will be helped by the stated solution -- but voting to reopen nonetheless.

After much try-and-error, I figured out the cause. My last command was insufficient. This command line:
make -j$(nproc) DESTDIR=/home/user/project/myapp.AppDir install

should instead be:
make -j$(nproc)
make -j$(nproc) DESTDIR=/home/user/project/myapp.AppDir install

or
make -j$(nproc) && make -j$(nproc) DESTDIR=/home/user/project/myapp.AppDir install

Furthermore, according to documentation:

Warning make install can overwrite or masquerade the python3 binary.
make altinstall is therefore recommended instead of make install since
it only installs exec_prefix/bin/pythonversion.

So make altinstall could be used instead of make install if needed.

